# accessing requestParameters when using AJAX - Symfony

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, symfony1

I have a form that is a drop down select list.

I also have an action, that looks for the request parameter:

indexAction:

```
if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest())
{
  $this->setLayout('layout');
}
 $param = $this->getRequestParameter('type');

  if($param == 'video')
  {
    isicsBreadcrumbs::getInstance()->addItem('All Videos', '@homepage');
    $pager = new sfPropelPager('Item', 15);
    $pager->setPage($request->getParameter('page', 1));
    $pager->setPeerMethod('doSelectLatestVideo');
    $pager->init();
    $this->pager = $pager;
  }
  elseif($param == 'photo')
  {
    isicsBreadcrumbs::getInstance()->addItem('All Photos', '@homepage');
    $pager = new sfPropelPager('Item', 15);
    $pager->setPage($request->getParameter('page', 1));
    $pager->setPeerMethod('doSelectLatestPhoto');
    $pager->init();
    $this->pager = $pager;
  }
}
```

Now this works fine when the url is: example.com?type=video - it loads the video content

The problem is, I'm wanting to update the content using AJAX and because I'm doing it via AJAX, I'm struggling to get the requestParamater, since it is no longer in mu URL;

ajax function:

```
$("#filter-form-newsroom .submit").live('click', function(e){
$("#search-results").html(ajax_loading);
var content_type = $("#filter-form-newsroom #type").val();
$.ajax(
 {
    url: "",
    type: "GET",
    data: "?type=" + content_type,
    success: function(data){
    var $response=$(data);
    var filtered_response = $response.find('.post');
   $("#search-results").html(filtered_response).hide().fadeIn("fast");
  }
  });
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

This function checks the parameter in my select list and is supposed to filter by the requestParamter, but it isn't working.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than putting ?type=" into the `data` property, put it in the `url`. Wouldn't that result in the same request you get when you type the URL yourself?

Comment: Excellent! I removed the data and added the ?type= to the url and works perfect!